# C++/WinRT project crashes when calling into C# Windows Runtime component

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-winrt

I have a Windows Runtime component written in C# (call it TreeDumpLibrary) and a C++/WinRT UWP app. 
The app references the C# WinRT component and calls a static function in a class in the WinRT component. Everything builds, however at runtime I get an exception

> when trying to activate: 0x80131040 : The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference.

I checked the generated **appxmanifest** for my app and it lists my classes as **activatableClasses** through **uwpshim.exe** which I believe is .net's solution for hosting winrt components/WinMDs.

I turned on loader snaps in my app, and I see that **TreeDumpLibrary.winmd** is successfully loaded, and then we decide to look for a **TreeDumpLibrary.dll** which doesn’t exist.

What am I missing? How can I call a C# static method from C++/WinRT?

Comment: That may be due to [a known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6d0d04e8-1471-4343-a78e-65c6405080cc/winrt-component-works-in-c-but-not-in-c?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: Update: We've identified a fix and we're pursuing a public doc update. In the meantime here's [how to consume a C# WinRT component from C++/WinRT](https://github.com/asklar/WinRTComponent/blob/master/README.md)